# How do you close the @: Razor operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know the `@:` operator allows me to access javascript variables from inside an mvc directive but I do not know how to close that operator.

I have the following code:

```
var temp = 123
@{ Html.RenderAction("DeliveredShipmentDetailView", "PartialPages", new {orderId = @:temp});}
```

When I run this code I get an error message of

> "The code block is missing a closing "}" character"

I know this is being caused by the `@:` character causing the closing character to be considered as javascript but do not know how to fix this problem. Since wrapping the operator in parenthesis will have the same effect it is not having.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't assign C# variable from JavaScript in this way.

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser, Razor runs on the server. There is no "magical" way to transfer browser data to the server. If you want to do that, you have to do so with a separate AJAX request, but that will be far too late for that particular Razor template, because it will be a separate request. You might want to read up on what ASP.NET MVC really does for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it wrong. @: does **not** allow you to access JS variables inside razor c# code.
In fact, nothing allows that, since it's impossible. Razor is executed on the server as the html is being rendered, while the JS code is executed on the client browser. Hence, no way to access JS variables directly in Razor syntax.

What @: actually does is allow you to output plain text from inside a block of C# code in Razor.

example:

One way to output text from inside a c# code block

```
@if (foo) {
  <text>Plain Text</text> 
}
```

or with @:

```
@if (foo) {
  @:Plain Text is @bar
}
```

same thing...

Click [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) for a quick reference

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the @: because you already *are* in a code part within that helper statement.

Update: The above is true if `temp` is a C# variable, not a Javascript variable. You can't (by principle) use Javascript variables in Razor, of course.

Comment: That is not what @: does. @: is indeed used inside code blocks, only, of course, not at all the way OP thought it is used. @: outputs plain text from inside code blocks.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why you wouldn't need it in a code block if the variable is from C#. If it was a JS variable, it wouldn't work anyway!

Comment: Still, your answer makes it sound like if you weren't inside a code block and you wanted to insert a c# variable, you would use @: which is not correct.